# How much will my voice improve as I grow up?

Tags: voice

I am a male 17 years teenager, and I have a vocal range that goes C2-F2 in vocal fry, and then I can go up to F#5, but with very little quality. I started practicing the high notes a short time ago, because it had always been my weak spot, considering that the quality of my four and five octaves aren't so good.

I have two questions, first: When I become an adult will I be able to hit (with quality) the low notes that now I just can hit with vocal fry? And second, with the time and proper training, will I be able to hit notes on the fourth and fifth octave with quality?

Answer (score 2):

Your voice will reach maturity probably toward your mid to late twenties, so you've still got about 10 years to go before you arrive at your adult voice.

A couple things to notice:

1) Are you sure you mean F#5? The average girl can't sing that high -- I'm thinking you mean F#4.

2) I'm interested to know what you mean by "practicing" the high notes. The voice is an instrument that must be handled properly, and straining to stretch your range can do damage. Vocal training must be done properly.

That being said, *if* trained properly, yes, you can expect your quality and range to improve over the next decade. My recommendation is to find a good voice teacher, with the second-best option being to find a good book (or several) about voice training.

Comment: For the matter, can the question asker hit F#5 with falsetto?

Comment: I thought of that, but in my mind that's a different type of range, and even then would be a stretch for most men, especially if they can hit as low as C2.

Comment: Thank you for you answer :), and no, i don't mean F#4, i am able to hit the F#5 with a falsetto voice, i think i didn't made it much clear, and what i mean is that i had singing classes, but i always worried just with the low notes, and just recently started trying to improve all aspects of the voice.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd say as long as you continue your training, you can expect to see improvement as your voice matures. I'd be curious to know what your full voice range is, not counting the falsetto/fry range.